# Broken dropdown menu in Wordpress

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, drop-down-menu

I'm making a website in Wordpress and there's one bit where I need to use a dropdown menu to select different options. I don't know what I did wrong and honestly, I don't really know what I'm doing. The site in question is:

http://www.lukegartland.com/final/

As you can see, there is a dropdown menu that you can't actually click on. But when you hit the TAB key a few times and hit the spacebar, it opens up the menu. I'll link to my sourcecode for the page below.

```html
<?php
/**
 * The Header for our theme.
 *
 * Displays all of the <head> section and everything up till <main>
 * and the left sidebar conditional
 *
 * @since 1.0.0
 */
?><!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]><html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7" <?php language_attributes(); ?>><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]><html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8" <?php language_attributes(); ?>><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]><html class="no-js lt-ie9" <?php language_attributes(); ?>><![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--><html class="no-js" <?php language_attributes(); ?>><!--<![endif]-->
<head>
<meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title><?php wp_title( '|', true, 'right' ); ?></title>

<link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11" />
<link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo( 'pingback_url' ); ?>" />
<!--[if IE]><script src="<?php echo BAVOTASAN_THEME_URL; ?>/library/js/html5.js"></script><![endif]-->
<?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>
<?php
$bavotasan_theme_options = bavotasan_theme_options();
$space_class = '';
?>
<body <?php body_class(); ?>>

 <div id="page">

  <header id="header">
   <nav id="site-navigation" class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <h3 class="sr-only"><?php _e( 'Main menu', 'arcade' ); ?></h3>
    <a class="sr-only" href="#primary" title="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Skip to content', 'arcade' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Skip to content', 'arcade' ); ?></a>

    <div class="navbar-header">
     <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
    </div>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
     <?php
     $menu_class = ( is_rtl() ) ? ' navbar-right' : '';
     wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary', 'container' => '', 'menu_class' => 'nav navbar-nav' . $menu_class, 'fallback_cb' => 'bavotasan_default_menu', 'depth' => 2 ) );
     ?>
    </div>
   </nav><!-- #site-navigation -->

    <div class="title-card-wrapper">
                <div class="title-card">
        <div id="site-meta">
<p style="display: inline-block; color: #fff; background-color: #fff; width: 45%; height: 200px; border-radius: 5px; margin: 1em; box-shadow: 0px 4px 11px #000; font-size: font-family: 'Roboto Condensed'; font-size: 22px;
color: #464549;"> // Start of Box

</br></br></br></br>Please select your location: 
<h1 style="margin-top: -42%;"><img src="http://lukegartland.com/mykids/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/LogoImagesmall.png"></h1>


// The following is the dropdown in question
      
<select id="foo">
     <option value="#">-</option>
     <option value="http://www.lukegartland.com/final/map">Maynooth</option>
     <option value="http://www.lukegartland.com/final/map">Celbridge</option>
  <option value="http://www.lukegartland.com/final/map">Leixlip</option>
  <option value="http://www.lukegartland.com/final/map">Dublin</option>
</select>

<script>
    document.getElementById("foo").onchange = function() {
        if (this.selectedIndex!==0) {
            window.location.href = this.value;
        }        
    };
</script>
</p>

         <h1 id="site-title">
          <a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url() ); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ) ); ?>" rel="home"><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></a>
         </h1>

       <?php if ( $bavotasan_theme_options['header_icon'] ) { ?>
         <i class="fa <?php echo $bavotasan_theme_options['header_icon']; ?>"></i>
         <?php } else {
          $space_class = ' class="margin-top"';
         } ?>

         <div id="sitedescript"<?php echo $space_class; ?>>
          <?php bloginfo( 'description' ); ?>
         </div>

         
        </div>

        <?php
        // Header image section
        bavotasan_header_images();
        ?>
    </div>
   </div>

  </header>

  <main>
```

Comment: Hi there. I've trimmed "thanks lads" from your post, as we have people of all genders answering here.

Answer (score 0):

Yours h1 tag have huge padding-bottom and it is covering select-box remove that padding

```
h1#site-title {padding-bottom:13%;}
```

in style.css file

Comment: The problem is not generally solved with this. It only helps on some screen resolutions. The problem doesn't even appear on all viewport sizes.

Answer (score 0):

There is a h1 element without content but still covering the select box. This happens because the h1 has a negative margin and relative positioning and therefore gains a higher stacking order than the select.

Either remove the following positioning rules from the h1:

```
#site-title {
    position: relative;
    margin: -19%;
}
```

or give the select higher stacking level:

```
#foo {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 100;
}
```

[About CSS Stacking](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/09/15/the-z-index-css-property-a-comprehensive-look/)